# Evitar que o script siga links simbólicos

Tags: shell, bash, diretório

Com o script em baixo, é realizada uma pesquisa a todos os alojamentos existentes na diretoria indicada de forma a obter os endereços de email associados a cada alojamento:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Scan All available email account addresses
# for homedir under the provided path
# 2014-12-19 Salustiano Silva

# Control :: Provided directory supplied ?
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "É preciso passar como parâmetro o caminho completo para a diretoria 'home'!"
    exit
fi

HOMEDIR="$1"

# Control :: Provided directory exists ?
if [ ! -d "$HOMEDIR" ]; then
    echo "A diretoria $HOMEDIR não foi localizada, verifique os dados fornecidos!"
    exit    
fi


HOMEDIR="$1"
CPANELUSERS=`ls -1A /var/cpanel/users/`

count=1
for x in `echo -n "$CPANELUSERS"`;do
  wiersz=`grep -i ^dns /var/cpanel/users/"$x" |cut -d= -f2`
  DOMAIN[$count]=$wiersz
  count=$[$count+1]
  echo "Login:        `echo "$x"`"


    for i in `echo "${DOMAIN[@]}" | sed  's/ /\n/g'`;do
      for n in ` ls -A "$HOMEDIR""$x"/mail/"$i"/ 2>/dev/null`;do

           if   [ "$n" == "cur" ];then echo "$n" > /dev/null
           elif [ "$n" == "new" ];then echo "$n" > /dev/null
           elif [ "$n" == "tmp" ];then echo "$n" > /dev/null
           elif [ "$n" == "" ];then echo "$n" > /dev/null
           else
           echo  "$n"@"$i"
           fi
      done
    done
    echo;echo;
done
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
./getMails /home/ > lista.txt
```

Resultado no ficheiro `lista.txt`:

```
Login:        example
renato@example.com
joao@example.com
carlos@example.com
manuel@example.com
suporte@example.com
newsletter@example.com


Login:        test
renata@test.com
joana@test.com
carla@test.com
manuela@test.com
suporte@test.com
newsletter@test.com
```

## Pergunta

Como posso prevenir que o script siga links simbólicos para outras localizações, realizando a pesquisa apenas com diretorias "regulares" ?

Comment: Eu não entendo muito `bash`, apesar de ter conhecimento de sistemas like-unix, será que este link ajuda: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141485 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Deveria, apesar que, eu já tinha visto esse e dois outros no [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) mas pelos testes que realizei, o resultado é rigorosamente o mesmo. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Voce teria que criar um If testando se o diretorio descrito no for é um link simbolico ou não. Lembre-se em sisetmas like-*nix todos os diretorios são um tipo especial de arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `ls -l` e retirar as linhas que contém "->".

Rodando `ls -lA`, você vai obter algo assim:

```
-rw-------    1 root     root           576 Jan 21 16:22 .ash_history           
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Jan 21 16:18 dos -> /root/dos       
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           242 Jan 21 16:18 hello.c
```

Então você pode pegar só os nomes dos arquivos a partir do 58° caracter usando `cut -c 58-`:

```
$ ls -lA | cut -c 58-

.ash_history                                                                    
dos -> /root/dos                                                                
hello.c
```

E desse resultado você pode extrair só o que não tem ">" com `grep -v '>'` :

```
$ ls -lA | cut -c 58- |grep -v '>'  

.ash_history                                                                    
hello.c
```

Resumindo: troque seu `ls -A` por `ls -lA | cut -c 58- |grep -v '>'`

OBS: Esta opção vai incluir uma linha em branco junto com o resultado, mas o seu código já tem um tratamento para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de fazer `ls` em $HOMEDIR, use o comando `find`, desta forma:

```
find $HOMEDIR -maxdepth 1 ! -type l
```

O `-maxdepth 1` procura apenas em um nível da árvore de diretórios (semelhante ao `ls`)
o `! -type l` procura apenas arquivos que não sejam links simbólicos

Mais sobre o `ls` neste link: http://rberaldo.com.br/curso-shell-script-comandos-basicos-linux/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas como havia referido nos comentários na pergunta, eu já havia testado isso mas o resultado é longe do esperado, o `find` devolve-me o caminho completo e não apenas o `user` para poder construir o endereço de email, pelo que a solução terá que ser mais elaborada. Se tiveres oportunidade eu agradeço, entretanto continuo a ver se lido com o problema de forma a manter o resultado final atual.

Answer (score 0):

[Naõ processa ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

O teste `[ -L … ]` identifica ligações simbólicas.

```
for i in "${DOMAIN[@]}"; do
  for f in "$HOMEDIR$x/mail/$i"/* "$HOMEDIR$x/mail/$i"/.*; do
    n="${f%%*/}"  # o nome sem o diretório
    case "$n" in
      .|..|cur|new|tmp) continue;; # arquivos não interessantes
    esac
    if [ -L "$n" ]; then continue; fi  # ligação simbólica
    echo  "$n"@"$i"
  done
done
```